# How to split a column with 2 data type in 2 columns (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, types, multiple-columns

I have a huge .CSV file with information about triathlon races (People, Times, Country, Overalltime...etc) all in varchar...

The problem is that one column (Overalltime) stores datatime and varchar types.
The varchars are (DNS,DNF,DQ) while datatimes are (09:09:30) for example.

When I am creating the table, I have a column like this:

```
       overalltime
      -------------
        09:09:30
        09:10:22
          DNF
          DNS
```

**But I want to split that column in the table, to have two columns. One with the datetime values and another one with the varchar columns.**

What will be the best way to split that column?

Comment: If you are importing lots of files I would recommend using [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).  There are two basic patterns you could follow.  Either load all the data into a [staging table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)), and then write a query that splits the values into columns.  Or perform that transformation in the SSIS pipeline.  The function [ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) (SQL Server 2008, or higher), can help with the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to conditionally break your values into columns:

```
-- Ussing CASE to split rows into columns.
WITH SampleData AS
    (
        -- Provides sample data to play with.
        SELECT
            r.overalltime
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    ('09:09:30'),
                    ('09:09:30'),
                    ('DNF'),
                    ('DNS')
            ) AS r(overalltime)
    )
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(overalltime) = 1   THEN overalltime    ELSE NULL   END AS [Time],
    CASE WHEN overalltime = 'DNS'       THEN 1              ELSE 0      END AS DNS,
    CASE WHEN overalltime = 'DNF'       THEN 1              ELSE 0      END AS DNF
FROM
    SampleData
;
```

Returns:

```
Time        DNS DNF
09:09:30    0   0
09:09:30    0   0
NULL        0   1
NULL        1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

im no pro but the best way to do it would be to filter it out before importing into the database. you use .csv file then it wont be a problem to split them into datatime for one column and 2ndcolumn for varchar. then upload it when you already have two separate columns

Comment: The point is that I have like 300 .csv each one more than 100 records, so I can't filter them manually.

Comment: trust me it will be a bigger problem if you try to split it when you have already imported it. if it lets you upload it, it will probably will be a varchar type. then you have to split the date types and i think its better to do it in excel rather than in whatever software you're using. if you want to avoid the headache split feature then better import them the way they are. sorry cant help you more than this